# Jenkins pipeline script for getting commit message

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run a stage in Jenkins file on a particular commit message in GIT.
How we can get the commit message ? what is the env variable used?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. You need to be more descriptive in what your problem is, what you tired so far to make it work, based on that we can help.

Answer (score -1):

The full list of environment variables accessible from within Jenkins Pipeline is documented at localhost:8080/pipeline-syntax/globals#env, assuming a Jenkins master is running on localhost:8080